# Why do I get small screenshots with pyvirtualdisplay in selenium tests?

Tags: python, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay

I am using complex selenium tests and `pyvirtualdisplay` in order to take screenshots during the selenium testing. However, I am using the following code to create a `Display`:

```
 self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
 self.display.start()
```

and something like this code

```
self.driver.save_screenshot(savename)
```

to create a screenshot (where `self.driver` is a `selenium`-`webdriver`). However, the screenshots I get are much smaller that defined, like 911x197 pixels. Do I have to make some special configurations to get a better screenshot? So far I only can see small parts of the headless browser I am using for testing...

Answer (score 1):

Do you start your browser with "--start-maximized" option?

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def browser():
    opts = Options()
    opts.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    d = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1024))
    d.start()
    b = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```